# Recursive Searching Category and Their Children

Tags: c#, recursion

I have the following class:

```
public class Category {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Parent { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Now given an instance of a Category and url. I wish to get the Category where the url matches the category or any of it's children (or their children etc).

Therefore my function would have the following signature:

```
public Category FindCategory(Category category, string url);
```

I know recursion is the way to go and i have managed to come up with a solution. However i've definitely seen it done better but i can't find where. I'd appreciate it if someone could show me the easiest and cleanest way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: are you taking your data from SQL?

Comment: I don't understand your matching criteria. Given a Category C1 and a url U, are you looking for another Category C2 where C2.url == U?

Comment: _"I wish to get the Category where the url matches the category or any of it's children (or their children etc)"_ - if this is what you want, your result should be boolean, as the result will always be either the instance you give it, or null. Or did you mean to say that you wish to get the category whose url matches the given url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple recursive algorithm:

```
public Category FindCategory(Category category, string url)
{
    if(category.Url == url)
    {
        return category;
    }

    Category solution = null;    

    foreach(Category child in category.Children)
    {
        solution = FindCategory(child, url);
        if(solution != null)
        {
            return solution;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Note: this will find the subcategory that matches you should use JaredPar's Try if you want to know if the parent has the url or a child has it

Answer (score 3):

In terms of recursion the answer is pretty straight forward.  I would prefer the Try pattern over a `null` return though.

```
bool TryFind(string url, Category current, out Category found) {
  if (category.Url == url) {
    found = current;
    return true;
  }

  foreach (var child in current.Children) {
    if (TryFind(url, child, out found)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  found = null;
  return false;
}
```

Your question mentioned you'd seen it done "better".  Could you elaborate a bit on this?  I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: Hi cheers, this works well but i have accepted Nick Bray's answer as his method's signature matched what i was after.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use a stack data structure.  Something like:

```
public Category FindCategory(Category category, string url) {
    Stack<Category> categoryStack = new Stack<Category>();
    categoryStack.Push(category);
    while(categoryStack.Peek() != null) {
        Category cat = categoryStack.Pop();
        if(cat.Url == url) {
            return cat;
        }

        foreach(Category child in cat.Children) {
            categoryStack.Push(child);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```